# ISAPI rewrite on IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite, iis-express

With the release of Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and IIS Express we want to run our asp.net 3.5 websites on that instead of our iis5 instance on our local developement machines.

All of our code runs fine except for our url rewrite rules using ISAPI Rewrite. We choose ISAPI_Rewrite 3 because it's very similar to an apache .htaccess file.

How can we use ISAPI Rewrite with iis express?

Comment: Have you tried to install it yet?

Comment: Yes, i have installed it and tried to use it with isapi_rewrite and it didn't work. I'm not exactly sure if i'm using it right... or you have to mess with something in the config files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct from the Helicon Tech team: IIS Express isn't supported.

We'll that stinks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to modify IIS Express applicationHost.config in the same way ISAPI Rewrite modifies the regular IIS applicationHost.config. Usually it will be a module/handlers sections that will get modify. Find out what changes ISAPI Rewrite makes to the regular config (just diff it before and after the installation) and modify IIS Express config at this location: `**<user folder>\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config**`

Comment: Has this worked for anyone? I'm having no luck. As Paul says in his answer I think IIS Express is just not supported.

Comment: I had better luck using Helicon Ape. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562724/helicon-ape-with-iis-express).