# Helicon Ape with IIS Express

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, iis-express, helicontech

Is it possible to use Helicon Ape with IIS Express for URL rewriting via .htaccess? When I install it, it only configures websites in the full-featured IIS, not IIS Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ape comes with a program called **Helicon Ape Manager for IIS Express** which will configure IIS Express sites.

Alternatively you can modify Web.config to add these elements to `<system.webServer>`:

```
    <handlers>
        <add name="Helicon.Ape Handler" path="*.apehandler" verb="*" type="Helicon.Ape.Handler, Helicon.Ape, Version=3.1.0.148, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=95bfbfd1a38437eb" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
        <add name="Helicon.Ape" type="Helicon.Ape.ApeModule, Helicon.Ape, Version=3.1.0.148, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=95bfbfd1a38437eb" />
    </modules>
```